# Custom alert box not loading in android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webview

In my application , I have a `WebView` to load a web app.The login is done using a alert box which takes username and password. when i try to load the URL in android browser the alert box appears like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByjvqajSL2xNUVpwTndBVUcySDQ/view?usp=sharing). But when I try to load the same URL in my `WebView` it does not show any alert box .

After adding the following code

```
mwebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, android.webkit.JsResult result) {
                Log.d("JSALERT", message);
                new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()).setMessage(message).setCancelable(true).show();
                result.confirm();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

`WebView` shows simple alert box messages , but it does not show that custom alert box(the method is not getting fired).

In my app `WebView` , I wanted to show the login alert (which includes login fields and `Buttons`) .if any one knows the solution pls share with me

Thanks in advance

Comment: able to get `Log.d("JSALERT", message);` in log?

Comment: I deleted my answer.I didn't saw the exact code

Comment: if it is a simple alert , i was able to log the message ... for this login alert i could not get any message (function is not getting fired)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you see in Browser isn't actually an "alert box" -- it's an HTTP authentication dialog. In order to handle it, you need to override `WebViewClient.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest`, see [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

You can check the relevant code in Android Browser [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser/blob/master/src/com/android/browser/Controller.java#L1008) and [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser/blob/master/src/com/android/browser/HttpAuthenticationDialog.java).

Comment: Thanks a lot ,first of all i thought it's a custom alert , now only i realised it a HTTP auth request ...  The code you provided works like a charm.